# buildSessionFacotry is deprecated?

Tags: hibernate

`buildSessionFactory` has been deprecated from hibernate.
I am using

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

But it says the function has been deprecated. Whats new? please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buildSessionFactory()` has been deprecated in Hibernate 4
Use `buildSessionFactory(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)` instead

so do below:-

```
 Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry= new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
    SessionFactory sessionFactory= configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```